# MySQL SELECT where boolean field is NULL or false

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

OK I must be missing something really simple here. I just want to return all records from a table where the user_id matches (easy!) and the 'paid' field is either NULL or 0. My 'paid' field is a TinyInt (1).

My CakePHP model code is:

```
$workingRecord = $this->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Subscription.user_id'=>$userId,
        array('not' => array('Subscription.paid' => true)) // Not True, to catch both false or NULL values
    )
));
```

The SQL generated by CakePHP is like this:

```
SELECT `Subscription`.`id`, `Subscription`.`paid` FROM `subscriptions` AS `Subscription` WHERE `Subscription`.`user_id` = 3 AND NOT (`Subscription`.`paid` = '1') LIMIT 1
```

Common sense would say this should work. The problem is that that SQL will return rows containing 0 in the 'paid' column, but will never return NULLs.

Is there any way to return zero's and NULLs in the one stroke, without using 'or'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If your field is TINYINT(1), you should not have any NULL values.**  If you do, run a quick query to replace any NULLs with the default, and set the database field to have a default of 1 or 0.

Then, your code should be:

```
$workingRecord = $this->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Subscription.user_id'=>$userId,
        'Subscription.paid' => 0
    )
));
```

**Reason why it's not working like you'd think:**

According to [MySQL's documentation on 'NOT'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not):

> Logical NOT. Evaluates to 1 if the operand is 0, to 0 if the operand
>   is nonzero, and NOT NULL returns NULL.

So - in your case, you're saying `"NOT 1"`, which MySQL translates to `" = 0"`.

Comment: So is that a hard and fast rule, that you should never allow null in a boolean MySQL column?

Comment: @joshua.paling - Personally, yes - I always make sure the database is set up correctly - if it's meant to have a boolean value (true or false), then I always make sure it can only have 2 values, not 3.  Not sure if that's a general rule or not.

Answer (score 5):

When you left join a table with a boolean field, the result set may contain a NULL value even though the joined table's schema does not permit it.

So as a general case I would suggest:

```
where `Subscription`.`paid` = 0 or `Subscription`.`paid` IS NULL
```

Comment: I like to use `WHERE NOT coalesce(Subscription.paid, FALSE)` or `coalesce(Subscription.paid, FALSE) = FALSE` to avoid repetition, transmuting NULL to FALSE, so it's only a single boolean comparison